# Testing $routeChangeError can not set parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test the following code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, current, previous, rejection) {
    if(rejection === 'Unauthenticated') {
        $location.path('/');
    }
});
```

Here is the test:

```
it('should catch unauthorised route changes and route to log in', function() {
    spyOn(this.$location, 'path');

    this.$rootScope.$emit('$routeChangeError', { event: null, current: null, previous: null, rejection: 'Unauthenticated' });

    expect(this.$location.path).toBe('/');
});
```

However because angular controls this event any parameters I pass in to $emit fail to arrive at the other end.  In fact everything is undefined except 'event', which is populated with the actual event.

the route looks like this:

```
    .when('/welcome', {
        controller: 'main.controller',
        templateUrl: '/welcome.html',
        resolve: { 'authFilter': 'oauthFilter.factory' }
    });
```

and the authFilter looks like this:

```
(function(mainModule) {
    'use strict';
    mainModule.factory('oauthFilter.factory',
        ['$location', '$q', 'authentication.service',
        function($location, $q, authenticationService) {
            if(authenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
                return true;
            }
            return $q.reject('Unauthenticated');
        }
    ]);
})(angular.module('main'));
```

I've tried creating the controller too and injecting this with $q.reject('Unauthenticated'), the applying the scope but this doesn't raise the event at all.

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments need to be passed into $emit individually, rather than as a single object, i.e:
`this.$rootScope.$emit('$routeChangeError', null, null, null, 'Unauthenticated');`